# changes any excel causes an excel's function execution

Tags: excel

I have encountered an excel that has very strange behavior for me.

if I change any cell value any other excel, it causes to execute all the user-defined funcion in this strange excel.

I realized it by debugging macro.

I couldn't figure out which settings or statement causes this.

Any idea?

Comment: For UDFs, look in to [Application.Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel)

Comment: There is not any volatile usage.

Answer (score 0):

I too have noticed UDFs recalculating unexpectedly. See my question and answers/comments at [Need to stop UDFs recalculating when unrelated cells deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815150/need-to-stop-udfs-recalculating-when-unrelated-cells-deleted)

Because of this, I now steer clear of UDFs in favor of Excel formula combinations whenever I can.